# React Native View

Tags: react-native

Hello I am new to react native and i am having problems with the view. I am having trouble with the text input as it only shows very small. When i 
remove the container in the StyleSheet All Text disappears and the text inputs become big.

[image: Here is a sample image]

Here is my code

```
render() {

    return (      
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>

        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>


<View>
      <View style ={styles.textinput}>
      <TextInput 
                  keyboardType='ascii-capable'
                  placeholder='First Name'
                  value={this.state.firstName}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({firstName: text})}}/>

                  <TextInput 
                  keyboardType='ascii-capable'
                  placeholder='Middle Name'
                  value={this.state.middleName}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({middleName: text})}}/>

                  <TextInput 
                  keyboardType='ascii-capable'
                  placeholder='Last Name'
                  value={this.state.lastName}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({lastName: text})}}/>

                  <TextInput 
                  keyboardType='ascii-capable'
                  placeholder='Email'
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({email: text})}}/>

                  <TextInput 
                  keyboardType='ascii-capable'
                  placeholder='Address'
                  value={this.state.address}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({address: text})}}/>
                   </View>

                  <View style={styles.buttonModal}>

                        <Button
                    style={styles.cancelButton} 
                    onPress={this.editUser}
                    title="SAVE"
                    color="#343434"
                    accessibilityLabel="Save user."/>


          </View>
          </View>

    </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },

  textinput: {
   flex: 0,
  },
   buttonModal: {
      paddingTop: 20,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
});
```

Comment: its not clear what you want here, but i assume you want a bigger textinput, 
for textinput in stylesheet can you try 
{
 flex:1,
alignSelf : 'stretch'
}

Comment: `textinput:{flex:1}` may work for you

Comment: did not work sir. Still same

Comment: remove extra `<view>` above `<View style ={styles.textinput}>` and also make `flex:1` to textinput

Comment: It worked, thank. But why is the button suddenly at the bottom?

Comment: @kurokocrunch added answer and comment on button as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<view>` above `<View style ={styles.textinput}>` and make

```
textinput: {
   flex: 1,
  }
```

for button, try by commenting `flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'space-around'` one by one.